# Using compareTo to sort one array in ascending order

Tags: java

So I have to create an array of 5 chocolates, but I have to order them based on their quantities. I am not allowed to use the sort function.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Chocolate {
    private String name;
    private int quantity;

    public Chocolate(String cName, int cQuantity) {
        this.name = cName;
        this.quantity = cQuantity;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public int compareTo(Chocolate obj1){
        if(this.quantity < obj1.quantity)
            return -1;
        else if (this.quantity > obj1.quantity)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Chocolate[] ch = new Chocolate[5];
        Random rand = new Random();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        int result;

        int quantity;
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter name of chocolates");
            name = scan.nextLine();
            quantity = rand.nextInt((19 - 1) + 1) + 1;
            ch[i] = new Chocolate(name, quantity);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
            result = ch[i].compareTo(ch[i]);
            System.out.println(ch[i].getName() + " " + ch[i].getQuantity());
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

So basically I need to have a loop that uses the compareTo and orders the chocolates by quantity and then print them sorted. Cannot use .sort. Thanks

Comment: Is this a school exercise? Why cannot you use the `sort()` function?

Comment: Take a look at different sorting mechanisms (like bubble sort, merge sort, quick sort) ... these are all comparison sorts because they sort the given array elements just based on comparing two elements from the array everytime

Comment: @Alexandre she  specifically said we cannot use sort

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sort an array with only one loop. If you are not allowed to used `sort` method you can do it with a classic bubble sort:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < ch.length - 1; j++) {
         if (ch[j].compareTo(ch[j + 1]) < 0) {
             Chocolate temp = ch[j];
             ch[j] = ch[j + 1];
             ch[j + 1] = temp;
         }
     }
}
```

But you will need for in for to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do sorting without using any type of common sorting technique as long as you have these constraints:

1. The field to be used for sorting is integer or can be converted to integer.
2. The range of integer value of the field is within a small predefined range.

In your case your example satisfies both constraints.

1. You are sorting by `cQuantity` field which is an integer.
2. The `cQuantity` field is within 0 to 19 range.

What you can do is:

1. Create an `Chocolate[20][20]` array. Lets call it `sorted`.
2. Iterate over `ch` and put each `Chocolate` into the above `sorted` array using their `getQuantity` field as index. In case we have more than one `Chocolate` with the same `getQuantity` add them together under the same index.
3. Iterate over `sorted` and print its value if it is not `null`.

Here is the code:

```
Chocolate[][] sorted = new Chocolate[20][20];        

    for (Chocolate c : ch) {
        Chocolate[] bucket = sorted[ c.getQuantity() ];
        if (bucket == null) {
            bucket = new Chocolate[20];
            bucket[0] = c;
            sorted[ c.getQuantity() ] = bucket;
        }else {
            //if we already have entry under this index, find next index that is not occupaed and add this one
            for (int i = 0; i < bucket.length; i++) {
                if (bucket[i] == null) {
                    bucket[i] = c;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (Chocolate[] bucket : sorted) {
        if ( bucket != null) {
            //System.out.println("b");
            for (Chocolate c : bucket) {
                if (c != null) System.out.println( c.getName() + " " + c.getQuantity() );                    
            }   
        }      
    }
```

Comment: I''m not sure if I understood the last part, so for the sorted array, I have to use sorted.sort()? I can not use sorted() so how could I iterate over ch and assign it to sorted like you said without using sort?

Comment: @Abraham After last step2, your `sorted` will already contain `Chocolate` objects already sorted by `cQuantity`.

Comment: I am still trying to do it but cannot get it to work, I do not have a cQuantity field, what do I do if I make one? What I understand from your words is that I should sort cQuantity by sort(). If that's not what you mean, then I still dont get it

Comment: oh i see now! just learned how to use : and null thanks to you! The code prints all 5 sorted most of the time but sometimes the code prints just 3 or 4 chocolates

Comment: Good catch. I missed the fact that the random API can return same `int` on subsequent calls. To handle this we need to add two or more instance of `Chocolate` under the same index. For that we are creating two dimensional ragged array to be able to store them.